# Problem with Grade sync in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I try to synch `grade` I got the following message:

> 1:09 PM   Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.
>                 Searched in the following locations:
>                 - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom
>                 - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.jar
>                 - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom
>                 - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.jar
>                 - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.pom
>                 - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.1/gradle-3.6.1.jar
>                 Required by:
>                 project :
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (24 s 360 ms)

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And, also my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file is as same as below:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mytestapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
}
```